# Jar executable can't find main class - weird one

Tags: java, jar, executable

Hello I have a strange problem. I'm packaging an application with eclipse to produce an executable jar file and when I run it I get the error 
"Error cant find main class [...]".

When I run the same package from the command line example

> java -jar app.jar

The program launches.

What is weird is that the error occurs only with applications complied in Java 7 enviroment.

If I set project to java 6 everything works fine.

What should I do to run Java 7 jar executable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of your jre if its jre6 then it may be a problem try to update your jre to jre7 it coud do a trick..

Comment: I have x86 x64 jres 6 and 7 installed i tried to launch jar with javaw.exe 6 and javaw.exe 7 and error is the same.

Comment: try to compile using e option e.g.jar cfe app.jar pack.Test pack/Test.class

Comment: Nothing changed :/ i ll try to uninstall all java and reinstall again see if it helps

Comment: This did the trick for me, `Error can't find main class` was prpably due to that Windows was trying to run the .jar with JRE6 but the .jar was build with JDK7 in my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set main class in manifest file

Sample manifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.3.1 (Sun Microsystems, Inc.)
Main-Class: com.package.MainClassName
Class-Path: oc4j.jar
```

Make sure that you have set all these things like in sample jar file

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the JVM is not able to locate the main class associated with the Jar file, JVM uses Main-Class attribute from Manifest.mf to identify the main class associated

Seems like you have missed to Add Main-Class Attribute to the Manifest File that was used to create the JAr ,http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html might help

Answer (score 0):

By default a jar is not executable

Java archives are more often used as libraries where the `jar`  format compresses the code into a single folder. Such code is usually not run as an application (standalone), but there is a provision to turn a jar file into an executable application through means of the [Manifest file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Simply create a Manifest file indicating which class contains the 'main' method, to make your jar executable and include the Manifest in your .jar

Comment: I did that but it is still the same, I have this error only if I compile project with java 7, really dont know what to do :/